# aspx include vs ascx

Tags: performance, include, asp.net, ascx

I have many aspx page includes in my web form. I want to convert them to user controls. Just wanted to confirm whether there is any performance gain in doing so? I have 50 pages in which the aspx page is included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of user controls isn't to improve performance, but to improve maintainability and reuse of code.

Comment: And also it gives You possibility to communicate between main page and controls.